# Show hide button for div in a mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, html, show-hide

I have this simple code that hide and show a button when it is pressed:

```
<script language="javascript">
function showOrHide() 
{
    var div = document.getElementById("showOrHideDiv");
    if (div.style.display == "block") 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

When I have a `mysql_fetch_array()`, usually a while that select more result, how can I apply that code into `mysql_fetch_array()`?

For example if I select 10 news from my DB, I want to see 10 buttons show/hide for each news.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is easily found using some junior level Google-fu. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yes but seems to be that php doesnt recognize the tag div.

Comment: PHP isn't supposed to understand HTML. Do you mean your code doesn't do anything with multiple `div`s?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and loading that in your page.  With jQuery you could do the following:

**Add after loading jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').toggle(); // initial state will be visible, then none if pressed
});
</script>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?PHP
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<div class="button"><?PHP echo $row['name'];?></div>;
<?PHP
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```